# Link to open email client and attach file?

Tags: php, javascript, email

Not sure if this relates more to PHP or Javascript/jQuery, but is there a way to attach a file to an email client (i.e Outlook), when user click on a link/button?

I have a link that generates a PDF and I want it so that, when someone click on a link, it will open up their email client with the PDF already attached, and subject already fill in.

I know, you can use `<a href="mailto:..."` but that only opens up the mail client. I also need to attach a file with a subject fill in.

Is this doable with PHP or Javascript?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Do you really need to pop up the mail client? You can set up mail header, body and attachment in php and mail it from there.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the subject line in the mailto with

```
<a href="mailto:someone@gmail.com?subject=Sample%20subject">MAIL TO EXAMPLE</a>
```

setting an attachment is not that easy and you would be better off providing people with a button that will trigger php to send the email (as per ott's comment).
In theory some email clients will support adding "attachment=path/to/file.txt" attribute but I have never seen it work